# 'menu-list' is not a known element lazy loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using lazy loading in ionic 3.6.1 and got follow error. Any idea what is the issue?

> 'menu-list' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'menu-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'menu-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

home.html

```
<menu-list></menu-list>
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import { MenuListComponent } from "../../components/menu-list/menu-list";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    MenuListComponent
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

menu-list.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'menu-list',
  templateUrl: 'menu-list.html'
})
export class MenuListComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello MenuListComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

components.module.ts (generated, no modified)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuListComponent } from './menu-list/menu-list';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [MenuListComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [MenuListComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: Why do you import menulist component in two modules? I am not sure it's lazy loaded. Look: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: In your `home.module.ts` move `MenuListComponent` from `imports` to `declarations`

Comment: @Duannx it's still not working. same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the **ComponentsModule** in which your component is exported from and not the component itself.

Check the official blog [here](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/).
In **home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    ComponentsModule //here
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```